# Straight Pipe Thread

Tags: pipelines, threads

Is there any National Pipe Thread Straight (non-tapered, requires O-ring or compression olive) that is compatible, even loosely, with a machine thread threaded rod? I want to put a reducer on the end of a pipe threaded with NPTS and reduce to like 1/4 inch NPTS nominal and have that reducer ride on a 5/16-18 threaded rod.  So it's like a shoring jack or lolly column, but really cheap, and the threaded rod can fit through a small clearance and guide the end of the pipe to the bearing point.

Answer (score 1):

NPS as defined in ASTM A 530 is all tapered and has no "O" rings or torque shoulders.

Comment: ok, so what is straight non-tapered threaded pipe called

Comment: One choice would be the same pitch and profile as threaded rod or a  fastener .

Comment: not too helpful

Answer (score 0):

British Standard parallel pipe threads aren't tapered (as the name implies), BSPP for short. That might work for you.

Comment: looks like a possibility

Comment: might be a problem to find the tap/die set for cutting those threads.